# Python3 | Можно ли как-то повлиять на скорость отправки email сообщений

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

Мне нужно массово отправлять сообщения, так как я пытался увеличить скорость отправки, но результатов ноль, похоже что лимитируется у smtp сервера.

Я так подумал, а как тогда обходить данный лимит? 
У меня был один вариант это - подключать новые аккаунты в отдельном потоке.
Но если бы аккаунтов у меня было свыше 10 тысяч, то 10 тысяч функций я не смог бы написать

Но результат это тоже не принесло, что делать? 
Все это мне для практики и понятия smtp протокола.

Answer (score 1):

Да вы правы. Будет ряд ограничений на smtp сервера.
Например как происходит отправка сообщения:

1. Ваш скрипт пакует сообщение.
2. Ваше сообщение попадает в очередь на
   отправку посчтовика.
3. Почтовик проверяет коректность заголовком. Не
       корректные заголовки - чаще удаление сообщения.
4. Почтовик подписывает сообщения, например dkim Сообщение попадает в очередь отправки.И тут есть ряд ограничений - например количество на отправку разово -
   стандартно 30 шт.
5. Почтовик соединяется с почтовиком получателя.
6. Далее самое интересное:
7. Почтовик получателя инициирует фальшивую перегрузку, и отдает
   стандартный SMTP заголовок - я зянят.
8. Ваш почтовик согласно настройкам ждет некоторое время, потом постарается выполнить доставку вашего письма.

Почему фальшивый ответ о перегрузке - спамеры не держат сессию.
Про фильтрацию входящих я немного промолчу.

Ну это было упрощенно. а так для почтовых сообщений существуют хотя бы RFC 5321 — Протокол SMTP

а с другой стороны нужно смотреть на доменное имя.
возьму для примера admin@mail.ru
от имени этого аккаунта идет рассылка, то на все почтовые ящики принадлежжащие домену (mail.ru)  письма придут практически мгновенно - почтовый сервер просто по факту из папки admin/Исходящие переложит письмо в папку Reciver/входящие...

Но вот отправка на сторонний ресурс, ну например с admin@mail.ru to admin@yandex.ru  может вызвать ответ, что яндекс скажет что немного занят - и сервер отправителя повторит отправку...

если же вы шлете не через почтовик - то шансы на то, что письма дойдут - очень мало вероятны...

Comment: спасибо, теперь я понял. Кстати про сессию, я знаю что можно связаться с сессией через requests, для того чтоб авторизироватся или корректно подать запрос, но можно отправлять запросы без сессии, или отправлять многопоточно, данная схема применима к smtp ? Если не удерживать сессию, или я что-то не понимаю

Comment: Имелось ввиду вы открыли сессию. Закинули письмо, и тут же разорвали соединения, не дождавшись ответа сервера. По вопросу многопоточности - ну установите вы миллион сессий. Потому как в потоке ИМХО будет выполняться так же как и в обычном скрипте только парралельно. Вы бы виртуалку подняли бы у себя, почтовик - да поэсперементировали бы